# Looping batch file for Merging several text files from different folders to one text file in another different folder

Tags: loops, batch-file

I am trying to merge text files as follows:

> NEWS.txt in ‘NEWS’ FOLDER.
> CINEMA.txt in ‘PGM’ FOLDER.
> COMM.txt in PGM FOLDER.

All the text files are in Unicode and have to be merged in

> CINEMA-SCROLL.txt in ‘COMBINED SCROLL’ Folder.

And I tried this following code but doesn’t work:

```
{@echo off
D:\MEDIA\GRAPHICS\NAS TICKER\ >For %%f in (PGM\CINEMA.txt   NEWS\NEWS.txt   PGM\COMM.txt) do type "%%~f" > "COMBINED SCROLL\CINEMA-SCROLL.txt"}
```

And I can’t loop it so that it will automatically change everything in the merged file if it changes anything in merging files.

Comment: Your provided 'tried' code, appears to be a command entered at the Command Prompt, not a line in a batch file, or the output from running it in a batch-file with `echo`ing off. As you've used the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, we expect to see the actual line you're using in that batch file.

Comment: Mate! It’s a batch file I just didn’t use the echo off function.

Comment: No, you are absolutely wrong Zahid. When you use it from a batch file with `echo` off the output would contain the prompt, _(which in your case is `D:\MEDIA\GRAPHICS\NAS TICKER`)_, and what you'd see in that window is `D:\MEDIA\GRAPHICS\NAS TICKER>For %f in (PGM\CINEMA.txt NEWS\NEWS.txt PGM\COMM.txt) do type "%~f"  1>"COMBINED SCROLL\CINEMA-SCROLL.txt"`, not `D:\MEDIA\GRAPHICS\NAS TICKER\ >For %%f in (PGM\CINEMA.txt NEWS\NEWS.txt PGM\COMM.txt) do type "%%~f" > "COMBINED SCROLL\CINEMA-SCROLL.txt"`. The content you've posted is neither that of the batch file, or the output at the Command Prompt!

Comment: Okay! Could you please make it for a batch file..!

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see your batch file, so I'm not in a position to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64303180/edit) and paste the actual content into it.

Comment: NEWS.txt in ‘NEWS’ FOLDER.
CINEMA.txt in ‘PGM’ FOLDER.
COMM.txt in PGM FOLDER.
All the text files are in Unicode and have to be merged in

CINEMA-SCROLL.txt in ‘COMBINED SCROLL’ Folder. I want to achieve this

Comment: Use the **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64303180/edit)** button under your question, copy and paste your actual batch file content into your question, _in place of what you have_, and this time please ensure that you format it correctly, _(using the `{}` button)_.

Comment: ‘’’{@echo off D:\MEDIA\GRAPHICS\NAS TICKER\ >For %%f in (PGM\CINEMA.txt NEWS\NEWS.txt PGM\COMM.txt) do type "%%~f" > "COMBINED SCROLL\CINEMA-SCROLL.txt"} ’’’

Comment: Both of my previous two comments, included a direct link to edit your question, as well as how to do it yourself, please do not post code in the comment section, where it cannot be read as intended in the correct format. Also, you should consider rewording your question because, it is not clear what you mean by "automatically change everything in merged file if it changes anything in merging files".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), or [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), you could probably use the `Copy` command, instead of using a `For` loop with `Type`.

Example:

```bsh
Copy /Y /B "NEWS\NEWS.txt" + "PGM\CINEMA.txt" + "PGM\COMM.txt" "COMBINED SCROLL\CINEMA-SCROLL.txt"
```

Comment: Mate! I need a loop batch file so that it will automatically update the combined text file whenever anything updated in merging text files.

Comment: @Zahid, I'm not sure what you mean by "automatically update the combined text file whenever anything updated in merging text files". If you're expecting one file to automatically contain the combined content of three other files, you'd need something other than a basic loop to monitor each of those files for changes. As your question code has not attempted those things, that part would be an off topic code request. We only assist you with a fix for an issue with your own code, we do not write new code for you which does something you have not tried yourself.

Comment: Thanks mate! Merging problem solved! But I can’t get the unicode fonts in merged file as it’s all written in unicode bangla font in sources files. How will I get that font in the merged text file?

Comment: Thanks mate! All problems were solved and I achieved what I wanted to do...! You are a star...!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
For %%f in (PGM\CINEMA.txt NEWS\NEWS.txt PGM\COMM.txt) do type "%%~f" >> "COMBINED SCROLL\CINEMA-SCROLL.txt"
```

Note `>>`, not `>` to append files, but this command would append the new files to any already-existing `"COMBINED SCROLL\CINEMA-SCROLL.txt"`

```
(For %%f in (PGM\CINEMA.txt NEWS\NEWS.txt PGM\COMM.txt) do type "%%~f" )> "COMBINED SCROLL\CINEMA-SCROLL.txt"
```

Should also work, but create a new file.

Comment: Hi Maggo! Thanks for helping me out. But As these all are  unicode text files how am I going to make it work?

Comment: Thanks mate! Merging problem solved! But I can’t get the unicode fonts in merged file as it’s all written in unicode bangla font in sources files. How will I get that font in the merged text file?

Comment: Thanks mate! All problems were solved and I achieved what I wanted to do...! You are a star..!!!